# How does PHP manage static and global variables?

Tags: php, caching, static, global, memoization

I'm trying to understand why a global value that should be cached in memory for the duration of the process lifetime is occasionally reset.

In particular this is the result of a method invocation which retrieves and returns a small JSON object--I'm trying to memoize this call by storing that value in a global and this seems to work most of the time. However as I mentioned, every now and then it's clearly being reset.

Does PHP ever reset static or global variables? [This blogpost](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2015/05/memoization-or-function-cache/) mentions something about an execution cycle and statics being reset as a side effect. This is accurate?

Comment: what do you mean by "being reset" ? you mean that the global variables are not anymore with your changes after the script output the interpreted code ? Not sure I understood your question, could you please supply an example ?

Comment: @EdenReich I mean that the variables are being reset--i.e. they become `null` even tho that shouldn't be possible once they've been set to the value of the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your question.
So I will try to answer it:

The key word to understand from that article you provided is that the variables you declare as static (global variables) are only valid for the "current execution cycle". Means if another process is executing that script, the scripts won't have the same declared static global variables, they will be completely "reseted". So normally when a request comes into the web server, the web server serves your PHP files on a separate process. As far to my understanding PHP "reset" the global static variables only after script is completely executed and NOT occasionally during run-time.

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Okay so I think this does make some sense: if the web server is spinning up processes behind the scenes (presumably there would be a pool of processes, not a process per request, but then it's possible that this pool is adding and removing processes over time) then eventually the value will appear to be reset.